# Python string formatting Error

Tags: python

My Python version is 2.4.3  and I am tring to run below code, but I am getting str formatting error.
Here is Error:

```
[xxx@bdm ~/python]$ ./run.sh
rfb.pcap
RFB\x20[0-9][0-9][0-9][.][0-9][0-9][0-9]\x0a
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "py_regex.py", line 14, in ?
print " ".join("{0:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in match)
File "py_regex.py", line 14, in <generator expression>
print " ".join("{0:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in match)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import re
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]
exp = sys.argv[2]
print file
print exp
myfile = open(file, "r")
try:
data = myfile.read()
p = re.compile(exp)
matches = p.findall(data)
for match in matches:
      print " ".join("{0:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in match)
```

finally:
    myfile.close()

Comment: `str.format` was added in Python 2.6. Do you have to use Python 2.4.3?

Comment: .format is available on 2.6+ , not on your 2.4 version.You got to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`format` method of string isn't available in python with version less than 2.6. Try the following, using the `%` operator:

```
print " ".join('%02x' % ord(c) for c in match)
```

Answer (score 1):

str.format was introducted in Python 2.6

From [the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format)

```
format(value[, format_spec])¶
    Convert a value to a “formatted” representation, as controlled by format_spec. The interpretation of format_spec will depend on the type of the value argument, however there is a standard formatting syntax that is used by most built-in types: Format Specification Mini-Language.

    Note
    format(value, format_spec) merely calls value.__format__(format_spec).
    New in version 2.6.
```